# How does this BJT transistor work without any connection to its base?

Tags: transistors, bjt

I came across [this circuit](http://cappels.org/dproj/simplest_LED_flasher/Simplest_LED_Flasher_Circuit.html) today and I am now wondering how that transistor works without any connection to its base. See below some schematics and a few images of it.

[image: Flasher schematics]
[image: Flasher in action]
[image: Flasher]

If it works, is it safe to wire transistors like that (for the transistor and the user)?

Comment: What does "work" mean in this context? What do you expect the transistor to do without a connection to the base?

Comment: For example is it possible to have a flasher circuit using that transistor without any base connection.

Comment: Phototransistors work with no connection to the base. Light releases current in the base region, which is amplified as though it was injected via a base connection. If you can find an OC71 transistor you can scrape the black paint off it to make a phototransistor (they were also sold clear, called OCP71)

Comment: If it's not important what it does, how do you define "works"?

Comment: You have a practical example for that? If the transistor work is not to take importance, why you want it? Maybe you have some final product and don't want to remove the transistor but it's base has disconnected?

Comment: Can anyone explain how the circuit in the link works? [http://cappels.org/dproj/simplest_LED_flasher/Simplest_LED_Flasher_Circuit.html]

Comment: @ScienceEnthusiast The link seems to be broken.

Comment: @ScienceEnthusiast There's an extra `]` at the end of your link in your comment. The fixed link is [this](http://cappels.org/dproj/simplest_LED_flasher/Simplest_LED_Flasher_Circuit.html)

Comment: @ScienceEnthusiast I didn't downvote your question, but to avoid that in the future, you should state more clearly the purpose of your question. In this question, you should have built it around that funny looking flasher, and definately should have copied the schematics as part of your question. I would have upvoted the question as I am also curious as to how the flasher works without any connection to the transistor base.

Comment: @ScienceEnthusiast - Why don't you rephrase your question to include more information about the link you posted? It will attract much more attention and certainly will get you a great answer from the fine folks from our site.

Comment: @ScienceEnthusiast - Actually, the answer to your own question is down the page you provided. TL;DR? Keep reading it!

Comment: For reference: Pease Porridge, EDN March 18, 1996; EDN April 1, 1996. The transistor configuration is explained there. Basically, one junction acts as an LED an the other as a photodiode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, this is a classic [avalanche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_transistor) relaxation oscillator circuit.

No it is not safe for the transistor, the reverse breakdown of the \$V_{BE}\$ junction will degrade the \$h_{FE}\$, so you should throw the transistor away after performing this parlor trick.

There are transistors designed for avalanche operation - which can create very fast pulses. I think they're mostly sourced from the former Soviet Union, at least one with a Western brand name.

It's kind of a fun circuit, most jellybean transistors will work, but you need a relatively high voltage (like 12V).

I suspect (but don't know for sure) that this won't work at all in a SPICE simulation (with the classic Gummel-Poon model).

Answer (score 3):

That's a known configuration known as [Negative Differential Resistance](http://jlnlabs.online.fr/cnr/negosc.htm) the 2N2222 just happens to exhibit that effect under that configuration and basically behaves similar to a [Tunnel Diode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_diode) . As mentioned in the article you linked you might not get the same behavior with other transistor.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the obvious phototransistors, I have quite recently seen the use of a transistor with a floating base in the the Alesis RA-100 audio power amplifier.

Here is an excerpt from the schematic:

[image]

QX09 is an an MPSA8599 PNP transistor in a TO-92 package. It's supposed to provide a thermal shutdown to the differential stage on the left by turning on QX10.

The repair manual text says: *"The biasing voltage for QX10 is determined
by a transistor (QX09 - placed in the heat sink) in parallel with a voltage divider at
the base of QX10. The base of QX09 is left open so that it acts like a zener diode
and can drop about 7.7V across it."*

Only problem is, QX09 is in the open-air in the middle of the PCB; it is not in the heat sink as the text says.

Answer (score 0):

Two simple equations of transistor is

Ic = b*Ib

Ie = Ic + Ib

If base is left unconnected and assuming ideal condition that no environmental interference, then from above formula

Ib = Ic = Ie = 0

Which means no current will flow at all

But in real life, transistor with unconnected base may work, depending on external conditions. In a simple LED driving circuit with transistor, touching the base with your fingers may actually make your transistor 'work', that is, conduct current with the tiny electricity in your finger.

Comment: I think you contradict yourself. You say that a "transistor with unconnected base may work" if you touch the base with your finger, but the "tiny electricity in your finger" is in fact a connection, isn't it?

Comment: In a sense, yes. But then, I regarded my finger connection and anything else as environmental interference and external condition that was not considered in design anyway. A better wording would probably be '... it would work if you forcefully inject current into the base by arbitrary means ...'

Comment: I think this answer is too simple to address the question asked.